# How to get the status of hardcoded QCheckBoxes in QSqlQueryModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qcheckbox

I have a `QTableView` that shows `QSqlQueryModel`. The model contains checkboxes that are created in each row in the first column (which contain the ref_no; the primary-key in my db) as follow:

```
void MainWindow::showM(model){
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    for( int i = 0; p<model->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
        ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i,0),checkBox);
    }
    ui->tableView->show();
}
```

... and it's working fine, displaying all the information I need plus the checkboxes.

Now, I need to get the ref_no where the adjacent checkbox is checked.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `QSignalMapper` (or an ad hoc solution involving a mapper using `sender()`, or lambdas). For instance define a member for the mapping:

```
QHash<QCheckBox *, int> m_mapping;
```

Then in your code hook it up like this:

```
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
ui->tableView->setIndexWidget(model->index(i,0),checkBox);
m_mapping[checkBox] = i;
connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &MainWindow::onCheckBoxToggled);
```

Then define a slot like this:

```
// for the love of kittens use proper names for methods
void MyWindow::onCheckBoxToggled(bool toggled) {
    QCheckBox *box = static_cast<QCheckBox *>(sender());
    const int id = m_mapping.value(box);
    // do something
}
```

Or, if you fancy lambdas, you can do the above with a capture:

```
connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, 
        [i](bool toggled){ /* use i, toggled */ });
```

---

All of that having being said, ***I would strongly recommend against the idea of creating `QCheckBoxes` and using `setIndexWidget`.*** Instead, employ a [proxy model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html) that enriches your column by returning the `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` flag and handles reads and writes for the `Qt::CheckStateRole`.